# BeautifulSoup HTML Table Parsing for the tags without classes

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have this html table: I need to get specific data from this table and assign it to a variable, I do not need all the information. flag = "United Arab Emirates", home_port="Sharjah" etc. Since there are no 'class' on html elements, how do we extract this data.

```
        r = requests.get('http://maritime-connector.com/ship/'+str(imo_number),  headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "ship-data-table" })
    for row in table.findAll("tr"):
        tname = row.findAll("th")
        cells = row.findAll("td")


        print (type(tname))
        print (type(cells))
```

I am using the python module beautfulSoup.

```
<table class="ship-data-table" style="margin-bottom:3px">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>IMO number</th>
                            <td>9492749</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name of the ship</th>
                            <td>SHARIEF PILOT</td>
                        </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                            <th>Type of ship</th>
                            <td>ANCHOR HANDLING VESSEL</td>
                        </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                            <th>MMSI</th>
                            <td>470535000</td>
                        </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                            <th>Gross tonnage</th>
                            <td>499 tons</td>
                        </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                            <th>DWT</th>
                            <td>222 tons</td>
                        </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                            <th>Year of build</th>
                            <td>2008</td>
                        </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                            <th>Builder</th>
                            <td>NANYANG SHIPBUILDING - JINGJIANG, CHINA</td>
                        </tr>
                                                                                <tr>
                            <th>Flag</th>
                            <td>UNITED ARAB EMIRATES</td>
                        </tr>
                                                                                                            <tr>
                            <th>Home port</th>
                            <td>SHARJAH</td>
                        </tr>
                                                                                                            <tr>
                            <th>Manager & owner</th>
                            <td>GLOBAL MARINE SERVICES - SHARJAH, UNITED ARAB EMIRATES</td>
                        </tr>
                                                                                                                                        <tr>
                            <th>Former names</th>
                            <td>SUPERIOR PILOT until 2008 Sep</td>
                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                    </table>
```

Comment: I am using the python module beautfulSoup.  Not using any regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go over all the `th` elements in the table, get the text and the following `td` sibling's text:

```
from pprint import pprint

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """your HTML here"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

result = {header.get_text(strip=True): header.find_next_sibling("td").get_text(strip=True)
          for header in soup.select("table.ship-data-table tr th")}
pprint(result)
```

This would construct a nice dictionary with headers as keys and corresponding `td` texts as values:

```
{'Builder': 'NANYANG SHIPBUILDING - JINGJIANG, CHINA',
 'DWT': '222 tons',
 'Flag': 'UNITED ARAB EMIRATES',
 'Former names': 'SUPERIOR PILOT until 2008 Sep',
 'Gross tonnage': '499 tons',
 'Home port': 'SHARJAH',
 'IMO number': '9492749',
 'MMSI': '470535000',
 'Manager & owner': 'GLOBAL MARINE SERVICES - SHARJAH, UNITED ARAB EMIRATES',
 'Name of the ship': 'SHARIEF PILOT',
 'Type of ship': 'ANCHOR HANDLING VESSEL',
 'Year of build': '2008'}
```

Comment: I like this solution.

Comment: @alecxe I get errors when the value is none.  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'.   where can I use the  try and exception

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
html = """
        <your table>
    """

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

flag = soup.find("th", string="Flag").find_next("td").get_text(strip=True)
home_port = soup.find("th", string="Home port").find_next("td").get_text(strip=True)


print(flag)
print(home_port)
```

That way I'm making sure I match the text only in `th` elements and getting the contents of next `td`